# ie's back button is being interfered by facebook api

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer

I'm using the Facebook 'like' api for my site, but there is a bug on IE (tested on IE8, and reported on IE9).

Whenever I hit the back button, it's inserting the following two urls into the "Recent Pages":

https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connec

http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/x

and each time the back button is triggered, one more of this pair will be "inserted". For example:

- 1st: opening page **A**
- 2nd: going to page **B**
- 3rd: going to page **C**
- 4th: hitting back button OR Backspace button
- 5th: now i'm on page **B**, but now there will be two more url "inserted" to the back button, plus the forward button which is suppose to be able to bring me back to page **C** now is blank/cleared so won't able to use the forward button to go "back" to page **C**

Thanks for your help in advance,
Chi

Comment: Do you have a channel file? http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/02/how-to--optimize-social-plugin-performance/